# Order of While Loops

Tags: c++, loops

So, I am fairly new to C++, and I am basically just trying to figure out how I would make things more user-friendly.

I made a fairly basic "calculator" type of program just to mess around!

It uses a lot of while loops for verification to make sure that if they make a mistake, they can re-input the data they want.

I am wondering, once it "outputs" their number, and the program ends, how would I be able to basically just output and then give them the option to restart (from the beginning).

Not sure if I explained that very clearly, but I am fairly new so I have no clue how I would do this seeing on how it is being read top to bottom.

Code:

```
int a;
int b;
string c;
cout << "1. Addition" << endl << "2. Subtraction" << endl << "3. Multiplication" << endl << endl;
cin >> c;
cout << endl;
while (c != "1" && c != "2" && c != "3"){
    cout << "1. Addition" << endl << "2. Subtraction" << endl << "3. Multiplication" << endl << endl;
    cin >> c;
    cout << endl;
}
while (c == "1"){
    cout << "Number 1: ";
    cin >> a;
    while (!cin) {
        cout << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(256, '\n');
        cout << "Number 1: ";
        cin >> a;
    }
    cout << "Number 2: ";
    cin >> b;
    while (!cin) {
        cout << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(256, '\n');
        cout << "Number 2: ";
        cin >> b;
    }
    cout << endl << "Output: " << a + b;
    c = "kevin123";
    cin.get();
}
while (c == "2"){
    cout << "Number 1: ";
    cin >> a;
    while (!cin) {
        cout << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(256, '\n');
        cout << "Number 1: ";
        cin >> a;
    }
    cout << "Number 2: ";
    cin >> b;
    while (!cin) {
        cout << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(256, '\n');
        cout << "Number 2: ";
        cin >> b;
    }
    cout << endl << "Output: " << a - b;
    c = "kevin123";
    cin.get();
}
while (c == "3"){
    cout << "Number 1: ";
    cin >> a;
    while (!cin) {
        cout << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(256, '\n');
        cout << "Number 1: ";
        cin >> a;
    }
    cout << "Number 2: ";
    cin >> b;
    while (!cin) {
        cout << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(256, '\n');
        cout << "Number 2: ";
        cin >> b;
    }
    cout << endl << "Output: " << a * b;
    c = "kevin123";
    cin.get();
}
cin.get();
return 0;
```

Comment: A big loop around all the current code?

Comment: Put your code in a function and call it in a while loop.

Comment: I would know how to do this in PHP as that was the language I learned before moving to C++. I would just make a function and then call that function in a loop at the end. Although, I have never messed around with C++ and this is the first thing I've written so I have no clue how to create functions or whether there would be an easier way.

Comment: you could definitely do with a switch statement in a few places.....

Comment: As @joachm said, one while loop and switch statements within the while loop would reduce the number of while loops you have

Comment: But what I'm asking is how to do these alternative methods! May seem like basic questions, but we all start somewhere. What I'm saying is that I'm not just asking what different methods are, I'm asking HOW I would use those methods as I don't know how. As I said, I am new to C++.

Comment: You might also consider sticking the "get a number from the user" code into a separate function so you aren't duplicating that `while(!cin) { ... }` bit everywhere.

Comment: I'm assuming your code has at least on function called main(); add another function following the same declaration syntax with a different name, and call the function. The syntax for calling functions is the same in C/C++ as in PHP... it's <functionname>(<parameter>, ....)

Answer (score 0):

I would say that your code need a bit of tidying up and refactoring. It repeats a lot of code, so you you should probably rearrange it to avoid that repetition, so for example:

```
cout << "Number 1: ";
cin >> a;
while (!cin) {
    cout << endl;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(256, '\n');
    cout << "Number 1: ";
    cin >> a;
}
cout << "Number 2: ";
cin >> b;
while (!cin) {
    cout << endl;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(256, '\n');
    cout << "Number 2: ";
    cin >> b;
}
```

occurs identical for alternatives 1, 2 and 3.

You could make that into a common section, and only do the final step of the math to produce the result in different pieces of code. This should be done with `if (c == "1") ...` etc, since you don't actually want to loop in this case (or use a `switch`, since you are never going to have both `c=="1"` and `c=="2"` at the same time, so a switch on `c[0]` would be fine...). This would get rid of the `c = "kevin123";` which is just an ugly hack to fix the problem that you are looping, when you don't really want to repeat things.

All of your validation loops could also be written as

`do { cout << "prompt"; cin >> input; } while(...)`

instead of repeating the prompt and reading of input.

Once you have made those modifications, you should wrap the entire main body of your program in another `while` or `do { ... } while(...)` loop to repeat the main body.

You could also make use of functions to perform reduce repetitions in the code.

It is a very good practice to learn from early on in programming to "do not repeat yourself" - do not write code that is identical or nearly identical - break the code out into functions, move it around so it's not repeating. This pays off in the long term, since when you need to change something, there is only one or a few places to change, rather than lots!

Answer (score 0):

What your are looking for is a **conditional outer most loop**. You have is `while loop` for all possible values. This code is something you can work with.

```
int a, b;
char c;

cout << "Welcome To Calculator" << endl;
cout << "Please Enter\n1.Addition\n2.Substraction\n3.Division\n4.Multiplication" << endl;
cout << "Enter 'q' for exit" << endl;
while(cin >> c) {
    if (isdigit(c))
    {
        if (c == '1')
            cout << "Looking for Addition" << endl;
            else if (c == '2')
                cout << "Looking for Substraction" << endl;
                else if (c == '3')
                    cout << "Looking for Division" << endl;
                    else if (c == '4')
                        cout << "Looking for MUltiplication" << endl;
        // Requesting new calculation.
        cout << "Please Enter\n1.Addition\n2.Substraction\n3.Division\n4.Multiplication" << endl;
        cout << "Enter 'q' for exit" << endl;
    }
    else
        break;
}
cout << "Thankyou for using the calculator" << endl;
return 0;
```

@user3646954:
The problem with your code is not only about the repetition of code but also the algorithm.

`while (c != "1" && c != "2" && c != "3")` checks for right the option (`1 | 2 | 3`). After which you loop around the options `while( c == '1 | 2 | 3')`. The loop doesn't makes sense since the loop will always exit after the first calculation (`c = "kevin123"; cin.get()`). You are never restarting your **calculator**.

The code snippet above removes the repetition of code for all options. The operator is requested at the start `while(cin >> c)`. After completing the calculation `ìf .. else if .. else if ..` we go back to the top. (check the code).

Comment: I don't exactly understand. How is this any different from the situation I'm already in? The only difference here is the verification for C, the condition for the while loop and the fact that you can exit. Still isn't a way to restart or anything is there? Unless I'm mistaken.